# Calling ASP.NET 2.0 web service from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, asmx

This problem a little bit more complicated than just calling a web method from the Js.

Here's the code I got on the ASP.Net side:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
        public KError GetAppServer(int version, ref KServerInfo serv, ref KUserMessage msg)
        {
        ......
        }
}
```

Where `KError`, `KServerInfo` and `KUserMessage` are simple serializable classes with only strings and ints in it.

When this service is used in .Net environment, there's no problems passing references to the complex types, but it doesn't work from the Js.

I've tried a lot of options (google doesn't really help on this matter) passing references to the serv and msg, but service keeps replying with 500 - Internal server error. Error description says that ASP.Net is failing to instantiate serv and msg from json data.

here is my Js part:

```
var app = {
          version : 1,
          SessionID : "''",
          Path : "''",
          Login : "''",
          Pwd : "''",
          UserID : 0
          };
var jd = { version : 1, 'appSrv': app, 'msg': msg };
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              url: "http://localhost:3965/api.asmx/GetAppServer",
              data: JSON.stringify(jd),
              //data: JSON.stringify(jd),
              dataType: "json",
              success: AjaxSucceeded,
              error: AjaxFailed
          });
```

and here's the exact error I'm getting from the server:

No parameterless constructor defined for type of \u0027API.code.KServerInfo&\u0027

Comment: Did you read this before http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/?

Comment: Can you add some peace of code of JS request so that we can identify the issue?

Comment: yeah, I did read that article and it didn't help

Comment: Why are you using ref for parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
var jd = { version : 1, serv: app, msg: msg };
```

Answer (score -2):

I think to call a service from java-script you need this line before your class

```
 // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

So your code should be like this

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public KError GetAppServer(int version, ref KServerInfo serv, ref KUserMessage msg)
    {
    ......
    }
}
```

Comment: it is there. I have using System.Web.Script.Services; at the top of source file and [ScriptService] at class definition, which is oretty much the same, because all other methods, that are not taking a reference to an object are working fine from Js